# In Erlang, is there a way to pattern match against an enumerated set of atoms?

Tags: erlang, pattern-matching

I'm currently picking up Erlang, and its pattern matching is one of the coolest things I've seen in awhile. One little toy function I've come up with in my exercises is as follows:

```
b_and(true, true) ->
  true;
b_and(true, false) ->
  false;
b_and(false, true) ->
  false;
b_and(false, false) ->
  false;
b_and(_, _) ->
  {error, invalid_object}.
```

I was wondering, though, is there syntax for telling a Variable in a pattern to accept only from a set of enumerated atoms? That way, I could shorten it to something like this:

```
b_and(true, true) ->
  true;
% We've already satisfied the only true case
b_and(ENUM(true, false), ENUM(true, false)) ->
  false;
b_and(_, _) ->
  {error, invalid_object}.
```

I've looked through the docs on pattern matching, but I couldn't find anything like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently there is no direct way to specify lists of atoms as pattern.

In your case you could use a guard but its hardly shorter

```
b_and(true, true) -> true;
b_and(A, B) when A =:= true or A =:= false,
                 B =:= true or B =:= false ->
    false.
```

Btw one would often leave the error clause off when it would be a error to call the function with anything else.

You could use this parse transform https://github.com/mad-cocktail/gin which woul give you a in() form for the guards.  The question is if it is worth it, just for such a little and not very often used feature having a parse transform seems a bit heavyweight.

Comment: Thank you so much. Is this the parse transform to which you were referring? https://github.com/mad-cocktail/gin

Comment: Yeah exactly, updating my answer

Comment: As per @Kaos suggestion: You should definitely NOT have an error clause in b_and/2! If it is called with a non-boolean argument it should generate an error. Generally type errors do/should generate exceptions, most of the libraries follow this rule.

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case, you can use the `is_boolean` function, which returns `true` for the atoms `true` and `false`, and `false` for everything else:

```
b_and(true, true) ->
  true;
b_and(A, B) when is_boolean(A), is_boolean(B) ->
  false;
b_and(_, _) ->
  {error, invalid_object}.
```

Answer (score 0):

I just want to stress the comment made by @PeerStritzinger about the error clause. You should definitely **NOT** have an error clause in `b_and/2`! If it is called with a non-boolean argument it should generate an error. Generally type errors do/should generate exceptions, most of the libraries follow this rule.

Comment: Robert, this would've fitted better as a comment to Peer's answer then, as it is not an answer by itself.. As a comment, I'd vote for it :)

Answer (score 0):

Just to give a different answer on how you may tackle something like this:

```
b_and(true, B) -> bool(B);
b_and(false, B) -> bool(B, false).

bool(B) -> bool(B, B).
bool(true, Res) -> Res;
bool(false, Res) -> Res;
bool(_, _) -> {error, invalid_object}.
```

But then again, you really shouldn't mask invalid arguments here, unless you expect to be called with bad args and want a error message returned rather than an exception.

Comment: Hi, why not simply : b_and(true, B) -> bool(B) ; b_and(false, _) -> false. bool(true) -> true ; bool(false) -> false.

Comment: That may be how we'd prefer it, but then you don't get the `{error, invalid_object}` for `b_and(false, foo)` (as I tried to hint at in the closing remark of my answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can just write this and it should be ok.

```
b_and(true,true) -> true ;
b_and(A,B) when is_boolean(A),is_boolean(B) -> false.
```

As Peer Stritzinger says, if called with bad arguments, let it crash and ensure you call it with booleans.